# NullPointerException when injecting EJB in JBoss

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, javabeans

I'm trying to implement a singleton class that manages properties from my database. However, I'm getting a nullPointerException when I try to inject my database bean. Here's my code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
..

@Stateless
public class Properties {

    public static volatile Properties instance;
    private static Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>();

    @EJB(WHAT_TO_DO_HERE)
    private DatabasePersisterLocal databasePersister;

    public static Properties getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (Properties.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new Properties();
                }
            }
        }

        return instance;
    }

    private Properties() {
        System.out.println("starting");
        System.out.println(databasePersister); //null

        //initializing
    }
}
```

I'm exporting my project as a jar, and later, when I try to get the instance of `Properties`, I get that a `starting` printed and then a `nullPointerException`. When I try to inject the same EJB (DatabasePersisterLocal) from my other project, I get no error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need to name the EJB you want to inject in `WHAT_TO_DO_HERE`, name the target bean with a name, and point it here.

Comment: But I successfully inject the `DatabasePersisterLocal` in my project using only the `@EJB` annotation?

Comment: it also dependents to implementation too dude, sometimes in some environments you need name them :)

Answer (score 0):

Regardless the issue about bean injection that you are facing, I would like to clarify that is not posible to implement a Singleton with an EJB at least in the way you are trying to do it.

The reason is that the ejb instances are handled by the container. The EJB's Thread Model specifies that every request will be managed by an available EJB's instance, which was previously instantiated and allocated to an ejb list (pool).

However if you are using EJB 3.1, it is posible to use the annotation @Singleton which indicates to container that has to create just one EJB's instance .